# Не корректно копируется состояние из redux store в state компонента React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Не корректно копируется состояние из redux store в state компонента React, точнее первый раз копируется правильно, а второй раз копируется не корректно.
задача по адресу https://github.com/samsonin/uchet-react/issues/2
В компоненте Fields
при нажатии на кнопку ОТМЕНА некорректно заменяется state компонента из redux-store, а именно fields.is_valid всегда false, в то время как в redux-store app.fields.allElements[n].is_valid значения разные

код:
componentDidMount() {

```
    let fields = []
    this.props.app.fields.allElements.map(v => {
        if (v.index === this.state.index) fields.push(v);
        if (v.name === 'prepaid') {
            console.log(v.is_valid)
        }
    })

    this.setState({
        fields,
        systemFieldsHandle: 0,
        customerFieldsCounter: 0
    })

}
```

метод также вызывается при нажатии на кнопку Отмена

Answer (score 0):

проблема решена оператором развертывания